# Some functions not binding to props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to assign values entered in a modal to state variables on the main page. To do this I understand that I have to bind a function to the props from the parent element. The issue is when I'm doing this, out of the three functions that I'm trying to bind only two are showing up in the modal function.

**Main.js**

```
import './Modal';
export class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { foo : false};
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }
    handleShow(){
        this.setState({ foo : true});
    }
    handleClose(){
        console.log("Close something");
    }
    uploadFile(){
        console.log("File uploaded");
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Button id="button" onClick = {(e) =>
this.handleShow()}> Upload
            </Button>
            <Uploadmodal
                stateProps={this.state}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    handleShow={this.handleShow}
                   />
            </div>
}
```

**Modal.js**

```
function UploadModal(props){
<Modal show={props.stateProps.foo} onHide={props.handleClose} style={{opacity:1}} >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Upload File</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
           
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.handleClose}>
                    Cancel
          </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={props.uploadFile}>
                    Ok
          </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
}
```

When being called from inside the Modal function, the handleClose()  and handleShow() functions work just fine. But on calling the uploadFile() function I get an error saying `props.uploadFile is not a function`. On checking the props in the modal function, handleshow and handleClose show up but there is no key/value pair for uploadFile.

The Modal works perfectly fine on a different page and that page passes all the functions that have been binded. So I'm completely sure the modal code is working fine. Also note that any other function passed except handleShow() and handleClose() is not showing up.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do the two code snippets relate to each other? You seem to have missed adding all the relevant code. What and where is `UploadModal` being rendered and are you passing all the props it needs?

Comment: @DrewReese it gets rendered in Main.js when the button is clicked and the handleShow() function is triggered. That sets the foo value to true and show parameter in the modal uses that to toggle.

Comment: Please show us what the code is doing. I see only `Main` rendering a button.

Comment: hhmmm... that's weird. I spotted a typo in my code could you please try it again? on clicking the button a pop up window should be on the screen with 2 buttons.

Comment: Other than a button click handler I don't see where you've provided the relevant code. Also `onClick={this.handleShow()}` will just immediately invoke the callback instead of waiting for the button to be clicked.

Comment: @DrewReese... hey mate thanks for helping out in finding my dumb mistake.... on your behest I rechecked the actual code and realized that on adding the function uploadFile I never updated the call to upload modal to include the function as well...

Answer (score 0):

So I found the mistake in my code. The modal.js should pass the uploadFile function as a parameter while calling the `uploadModal`. I added the `uploadFile` function but never updated the call to the `UploadModal` function. The code should be :

**Main.js**

```
import './Modal';
export class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { foo : false};
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }
    handleShow(){
        this.setState({ foo : true});
    }
    handleClose(){
        console.log("Close something");
    }
    uploadFile(){
        console.log("File uploaded");
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Button id="button" onClick = {(e) =>
this.handleShow()}> Upload
            </Button>
            <Uploadmodal
                stateProps={this.state}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    handleShow={this.handleShow}
                    uploadFile={this.uploadFile}
                   />
            </div>
}
```